# MacBook Air running Yosemite won't shut down when external HDD connected

Tags: macos, external-disk, shutdown

My MacBook Air won't shut down when an external hard drive is connected. The screen goes black, and the mouse pointer is still there. I think this started happening when I upgrade to Yosemite. Any suggestions as to how I might fix this?

Comment: Just curious. Do you use products from AVID or X-Rite?

Comment: No -- this problem ended up fixing itself, as it happens; either that or I stopped using external HDDs habitually. Are you having a similar issue?

Comment: Yes, in my case it turned out a process called “hasplmd” which caused random Kernel Panics and prevented macOS Sierra from going to sleep/shutdown. I have shared a article about it here https://medium.com/@howdytom/hasplmd-prevents-macos-sierra-from-going-to-sleep-and-causes-random-kernel-panics-e96763d8612a

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure something is not still running...or something is preventing the disk from unmounting.

If there's a grey circle -- then it might be running fsck on the disk...

Now, another thread suggested:

> Start Up in Verbose Mode using Command-V
>
> Then issue: sudo shutdown -h now
>
> Also, more /var/log/system.log

This should show you what's occurring as it shuts down.

The sudo shutdown -h now is equivalent to the Shut down menu option.

Also, try going into Disk Utility and manually click on the Unmount icon.  I would just want to see if it will unmount normally.

If it doesn't, then, I'm thinking SOMETHING is still using  the disk..